# Citet does not work with alphaurl bibliographystyle

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I am using the `alphaurl` citation style.
When I use the `\citet` command, I get the following error (author?).
Is there any way to show the author's name using the `alphaurl` citation style?

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,%
11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort]{natbib}
%\input{preamble} 
%\definecolor{keywordcolor}{RGB}{127,0,85}


\begin{document}

Hello world \citet{Test12}

\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
\bibliography{memoire}

\end{document}
```

and in `memoire.bib`

```
@article{Test12,
    author = "John Smith",
    title = "Test Article",
    year = "2012",
    journal = "The Test Journal"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `usebib` package (please note the use of `{...}` in the .bib file)

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,%
11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{author}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Test12,
    author = {John Smith},
    title = {Test Article},
    year = {2012},
    journal = {The Test Journal}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}

Hello world \usebibentry{Test12}{author} \cite{Test12} 

\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works! One problem remains though...in doing so, I'll have to manually input the field for all my references. Is there any other (more automated way) of executing this?

Comment: @OrlandoAmaralCejas If you are only citing individual entries, you could use a macro like `\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\usebibentry{#1}{author} \cite{#1}}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, good way of remove part of the manual work.